# What are the reasons behind not using TFLite for production purposes?

Tags: tensorflow, production-environment, tensorflow-lite

The website states that TFLite is currently released as a developer preview and the APIs may change not guaranteeing the forward as well as backward compatibility.

However, what if the current APIs are enough for the problem to be solved and the model is working fine.

Are there any other reasons relating to execution optimality or technical or anything else that would, in detail, explain whether it should not be used for production purposes?

Comment: This issue is a bit old.

Comment: Yeah. It is not relevant now. The stable release is out now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a bit old. Take a look again at existing documentation and see if it answers your question. The things to consider are if the models execute fine (latency, accuracy). Assuming the above, you'll need to be careful about model/binary versioning (unless you decide to package the two together) and see if TFLite targets the platforms you care about. For instance, we're better suited for arm and mobile devices as opposed to x86 (with respect to optimizations).